# "Красивая ссылка" с редиктом на файл с переменной

Tags: .htaccess, apache2.4

Директория выглядит вот так:

```
\_res\
\admin\
\.htaccess
\index.php
```

Суть в том, что `index.php` может изменять язык, в зависимости от запроса.
Сейчас это `?lang=(rus|eng|est|ukr)`.

Как сделать, чтобы адрес выглядел следующим образом `/(rus|eng|est|ukr)`, при этом, если такое возможно, если условие не выполняется, то `/eng` "по умолчанию".

Ещё, чтобы это всё не конфликтовало с файлами из папки `/_res` и папкой `/admin`. Т.е. получается только на `index.php` (желательно без отображения его названия, т.е. `domain.ru/(rus|eng|est|ukr)`).

Сейчас файл `.htaccess` выглядит так:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} " (.*)\.php"
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример реализации:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?lang=eng [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Вот эта строка отвечает за вариант по-умолчанию

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?lang=eng [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Похоже уходит в рекурсию, но без ошибки, в адресной строке куча запросов `&lang=`

Comment: Ошибка была в кеширование страницы браузером, из-за этого и была рекурсия. Вставил ваш код, чуть чуть поправив.

Comment: Это был пример, можно по-разному организовать :)